# How to display Scrollbar in left side in ionic

Tags: android, cordova, scrollbar, ionic-framework

How can change position of scrollbar to left in android in ionic project for rtl support?

Comment: Can you show what code you have done so far?

Comment: I am also looking for same. have you got how to show scrollbar in ionic >=2

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `ScrollView` in `XML` file -

```
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
```

You can also do it dynamically. Call `ScrollView` in code and add this -

```
mView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_LEFT);
```

If any questions then ask. If you like this answer, please mark it as `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    In drawable :
       scrollbar_thumb.xml

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <gradient android:startColor="#3333FF" android:endColor="#8080FF"
     android:angle="0"/>
     <corners android:radius="6dp" />
     </shape>

      In your layout:

   <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrolldes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewId"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scrollbarSize="12dip"
            android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_thumb" >
```